# Как передать в QListWidget коллаж из нескольких изображений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qlabel, qlistwidget

Есть несколько URL-адресов картинок ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 и 5 картинка).
Адреса беру из Базы Данных SQL , каждая строка - 5 адресов .

Как можно собрать все эти изображения в 1 объект , чтобы после передать этот объект `QListwidget`?

Какие есть способы? Проще говоря я хочу , чтобы `QListWidget` добавлял как бы уже сгенерированный коллаж как 1 картинку , в которой есть ещё 4 внутри.

Может можно как-то собрать 1 готовый объект из 6 `QLabel`? ( 4 маленьких справа , 1 большой и 1 на котором будут держаться все 5 `QLabel`) , а после передать этот объект `QListwidget` ?

Прикрепляю картинку:

[image: qlistwidget]

Comment: что такое - `URL адресов картинок`? Приведите пример строки, которая содержит URL адресов картинок ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 и 5 картинка).

Comment: Суть не так важна , вместо url можно просто использовать картинки , просто я их беру сразу из интернета не скачивая. Пример :

url = "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png"
И далее просто image.loadFromData(requests.get(url).content)
Который можно передать в тот же ui.label_1.setPixmap(QPixmap(image))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import requests
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, urls):
        super().__init__()

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)

        for i, url in enumerate(urls):
            lbl = QLabel()
            image = QImage()
            image.loadFromData(requests.get(url).content) 
            if i == 0:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(210, 210)) 
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i+1, 0, 4, 1)
            else:
                lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(image).scaled(70, 70)) 
                self.grid.addWidget(lbl, i, 1, 1, 1)        


class ListWidget(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ListWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setEditTriggers(self.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)
        self.setSpacing(10)
        # Резиновая лента (для эффекта выбора рамки)
        self._rubberPos  = None
        self._rubberBand = QRubberBand(QRubberBand.Rectangle, self)

    def makeItem(self, lb):
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self)
        item.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(300, 300))
        self.setItemWidget(item, lb)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('ListWidget')
        self.resize(1100, 670)
        self.show()        
        
        self.listWidget = ListWidget()

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.urls = [
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png",
            "https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/phone.png", 
            "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
            "https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/random-pixels-wallpaper-big.jpg",
            "https://laguna-akul.ru/upload/003/u379/f4/61/8f68d93a.jpg",
        ]
        
        num = 5                                                
        for i in range(num):
            art = Widget(self.urls)            
            self.listWidget.makeItem(art)        
            QApplication.processEvents() 
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Leluch  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Чудовищное спасибо , я проверил код и мне стоит ещё очень долго его разбирать и подстраивать под свои нужды , но саму суть я уловил и выражаю вам огромную признательность , без вас на это ушла бы неделя , если не больше.

Comment: я наконец смог осилить ваш код , однако все ещё не могу изменить его под свои нужды. Мне нужно удалять старые объекты , который были созданы ранее. Я догадываюсь , что это делается посредством takeitem() , но не могу понять , куда можно вставить эту команду и как правильно ей воспользоваться. Я просто хочу удалять старые объекты , когда их общее количество превысит 100 единиц. Вы можете дать мне подсказку?

Comment: @Leluch задайте новый вопрос. Приложите ваш пример. Опишите, что вы хотите сделать, что вы пробовали и что у вас не получается.